# How to install recess through npm on the terminal on windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, less, recess

I have installed node.js on my Windows PC, but when I try to install recess like so:

```
npm install -g recess
```

From the terminal, I get a list of errors.
How can I install recess on my machine?

**Here is the error list:**

```
C:\Users\King> npm install -g recess
npm ERR! Windows NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR!  code ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Comment: You have a better chance of getting your answer if you post the errors here. Now we can only look into our crystal ball to see what's wrong...

Comment: And just in case, if you're about learning/using Bootstrap - they gave up `recess` a while ago (make sure tutorials you use are less or more up-to-date... playing with absolute tools can be quite painful).

Comment: Hey  even if I try to install Less from the terminal, I get the same error...